# Find xml node in deeper levels recursively in c#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, nodes, child-nodes

I am trying to get the node in deep level for the xml structure.

My xml Structure:

```
<Level1 name="data_reply"> 
  <Level2 name="name1"> 
    <level3 name="name2" />
    <Level3 name="name3 > 
        <Level4 name="name4"/>
        <Level4 name="name5" someAttributes="blah blah"/>
    </Level3> 
  <Level2 name="name6"/>
  <Level2 name="name7"/>
</Level1>
```

I want to get the node named with "name 5" and it's attributes. The problem is i want to get this node even if it was deeper or the node levels are different. name attributes can be assumed as unique I mean that what i want is something like:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("FileFullPath");
var wantedNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetNodeWithName("name5") // Which can be recursive or iterative
```

My method signature could be like this:

```
public XmlNode GetNodeWithName(string nodeNameAttributeValue){
  ... Method content
  return myNode
}
```

Are there any ease to use method like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Xml.Linq`:

```
var item = xmlDoc.Descendants()
           .FirstOrDefault(node => (string)node.Attribute("name") == "name 5")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SelectNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx) which accept [XPath expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) as parameter. XPath supports expressing a query to find element of any name, anywhere in the XML document, where `name` attribute value equals  "name 5" :

```
var searchParam = "name 5";
var xpath = string.Format("//*[@name='{0}']", searchParam);
var wantedNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```